# Rounded bevel for selected vertices in a plane

Tags: vertices

I am trying to create a rounded bevel for two of the four vertices in this arrow shape:

[image]

I selected the left-most vertex, pressed ctrl-shift-b and created the bevel as seen in the picture.  However, the bevel is a straight line whereas I would like it to have a rounded appearance.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1: Setting with Scroll wheel

If you use the scroll wheel while in bevel mode the bevel uses more edges, giving the corner a more rounded look.[image]

---

### Option 2: Using the advanced tool menu popup:

There is also another way (which doesn't need a scroll wheel) to set more advanced settings for the bevel function (actually works for any tool and add primitive actions).

After you did the tool action (in your case bevel) a small popup is seen in the left corner of the 3d-view screen (in Blender 2.80) which you can click to expand it. There you can modify the action you just did.

[image]

[image]

PS: In Blender 2.79b this advanced tool menu was located in the tools tab

---

### Option 3: Use the +/- keys

As quoted from the comment from @lemon you can also

> "use + or - from the keypad." - lemon

to increase the segments of the bevel tool.

---

Happy Blending! :)

Comment: Lacking a scroll wheel (laptop), I use the 3 button mouse emulator.  Is there a way to do this given my situation?

Comment: @vndep, use + or - from the keypad.

Comment: I now added the "Option 2" which you can also use. BTW: The advanced tool settings menu is really handy to use. For example you can directly change the properties of an object you add (height, diameter, segments, location, ....)

Comment: @lemon thank you! I added your suggestion to my answer (Option 3)

Comment: Thanks for these great solutions!